# Set variable in succes function to overwrite variable in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
var offset = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {        
        jQuery('ul.productlist').scrollExtend(
            {   
                'target': 'ul.productlist',         
                'url': 'getmore.php?offset=' + offset, 
                onSuccess: function() { 
                    offset = offset + 20;  
                },    
                'newElementClass': 'more'
            } 
        );
    }
);
```

I am trying to use the new offset the next time the url is called (it is being called every time the page scroll down to get more results in a dynamic list).

I want to set the offset, so the php page knows which results to serve next. I understand this is not possible, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the next time the URL is called'? The next time you load up the page? Also, you have some quote issues in your code.

Comment: I mean this thing fires everytime i scroll down the page. It is for infinite loading of content. So the content is dynamically added everytime i scroll down the page. I need to set the offset somehow in the url that it uses for the new content.

The quotes are not causing any trouble so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
'url': function() {
    return 'data.php?offset='+offset;
}

'onSuccess': function() { 
    offset = offset + 20;  
},
```

passing the url as a function does the trick